# Getting a Syntax Error when creating new app on Rails, how do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby and Rails, I am following this tutorial;
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

when I try to create a new app by running `rails new blog` I get the following error;

`` /Users/gianluca/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:885:in `eval': /Users/gianluca/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/test.rb.tt:10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
);  if spring_install? 
^ ``

I do not really understand the error as I am very new to this language. Any help would be very appreciated, let me know if you require any details on my system.

`ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin18]`

`rails -v` gives `Rails 6.0.2.2`

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37680

And it does look like `rails` executable is using ruby `2.5.0`. Maybe you should install rails on your `2.7.0` 'gemset' independently? I'm only guessing though, I don't know `rbenv` very much.

Comment: @MarekLipka I am afraid I am not sure how to do that/what that means, will have a look online though

Comment: Do you use rvm or rbenv to manage your ruby version? If you type in `rvm -v` or `rbenv -v` you should be able to see

Comment: I am using rbenv, am in the process of installing ruby 2.6.5 with rbenv. That link that you sent implied that the version might be the problem, and it seems 2.6.5 is certified as working